# Logic gate with 00000011 output

Tags: math, logic

```
p   q   r   output
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
```

How can i make this output with 3 inputs(p,q,r)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is true if and only if p and q are true, so you can do

```
(p AND q AND r) OR (p AND q AND NOT r)
```

Comment: Thus, it can be factorized into `p AND q`.